# Test if a user has access to a link in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I'm new to phpUnit and Laravel 5.1

I want to test permissions:

I want to make sure that a link (Administration) that should be displayed for an admin should not be visible by a simple user...

To log in, I can do it like that:

```
protected function login_standard_user()
{
    return $this->visit('login')
        ->type('user@user.com', 'email')
        ->type('user', 'password')
        ->press('Login');
}
```

But then how could I test that there is no link "Administration" without making phpunit fail???

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the correct way of doing it or not, but you can put a `try catch` block around your code

```
$this->visit('login')
->type('user@user.com', 'email')
->type('user', 'password')
->press('Login');

try{
    $this->click('Administration')
    ->seePageIs('/admin');
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Exception Catched";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected function login_standard_user()
{
    return $this->visit('login')
        ->type('user@user.com', 'email')
        ->type('user', 'password')
        ->press('Login')
        ->dontSee('Administration')
        ;
}
```

I haven't verified it works, but it's documented here,

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#application-testing

...so it should be ok.